# What causes slow SFTP up/download speeds?

Tags: performance, sftp

Are SFTP up/download speeds something that's in the control of the hosting company? Can they throttle SSH traffic, regardless of the port?

I just signed up with a new hosting company. We'll call them Slow SFTP, Inc. I have another server with Fast SFTP, Inc. Both are in Dallas and both are in different data centers.

I noticed my SSH client (PuTTY) lagging when connecting to Slow SFTP, Inc., so I decided to run some tests from both companies. I ran several tests over several hours. I also changed sshd ports just to make sure traffic wasn't being throttled based on the port. It made no difference.

```
     | Slow SFTP, Inc. | Fast SFTP, Inc.
-----------------------------------------
UP   |    744 KB/s     |     352 KB/s
DOWN |    150 KB/s     |   1,723 KB/s
```

I find it strange that the download speed from Slow SFTP, Inc. is so much slower than the upload speed.

Note: These are 1:1 comparisons. Identical setups on both servers. No firewalls. Vanilla Debian 7/sshd installs.

Comment: What speed transfer do you get between you machine and each Debian box via a different protocol such as HTTP? Try something like `wget` the same file from the web root of both machines. You know to baseline SSH against something to determine if SSH/SFTP is the problem here or something larger.

Comment: Well maybe you could install one? :p Or FTP? Or just use iperf between them and your home/office test machine

Comment: No web/ftp server installed. I can't mess with one of the boxes, so that's a no-go right now. Seems like Slow SFTP, Inc. just fixed it (I had a ticket open). I'll give an update after they tell me what they did.

Comment: Different datacenters = different routing path. It's possibly the cause.

Comment: From support, "The number one factor that effects transfer rates is routing problems." So is my routing path to Slow SFTP, Inc. different just a few minutes after opening the ticket? I'll leave this question up just in case someone has any other ideas. @NathanC, Nice.

Comment: Datacenters can change their routes basically instantly depending on issues. I've had my own host do that a few times when routers would fail on a provider and slow things to a crawl. A test would be to traceroute your server and see the path it takes.

Comment: I compared an old traceroute with a new one. Both still hit the same edge router just before the server, but the four hops previous to the edge router are different now. If someone wants to answer the question (NathanC?), I'll mark it correct for any future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing can play a big part in speeds. As seen in the comments the datacenter likely had a bad route and swapped it when performance was suffering.

Answer (score 0):

The two companies can very well limit the upstream/downstream transfer speed with packet shapers. And most likely they do, especially if they're hosting companies. You only have a certain amount of upload bandwidth and a certain amount of download bandwidth. Plus, some hosting companies also meter the actual amount of transferred data, and after a certain threshold they "cut" your speed to a lower limit.

And to precisely address the main point in your question, YES, they can throttle traffic to/from your server (or virtual server) regardless of the port, they can set global limits per-machine, per port-group, or even per-service-type if they have a content-inspection capable firewall.